# rsyslog single filter conditional syntax

Tags: rsyslog, filter

I'm looking for a way to write a single rule with multiple match values, don't write those rows to logfile if the message contain first word or second word.

This works but isn't DRY:

```
if $msg contains "WARNING:" then { Action (type="omfile" File="/var/log/ignorethis") stop }
if $msg contains "IGNORE THIS MESSAGE:" then { Action (type="omfile" File="/var/log/ignorethis") stop }
```

this one doesn't work:

```
if $msg contains "WARNING: || IGNORE THIS MESSAGE:" then { Action (type="omfile" File="/var/log/ignorethis") stop }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
if ($msg contains "WARNING:") or ($msg contains "IGNORE THIS MESSAGE:") then { Action (type="omfile" File="/var/log/ignorethis") stop }
```

The [rsyslog expression documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/expressions.html) may help a little.